# Decoding instagram reply (php)

Tags: php, instagram, json

I am trying to get info from popular posts from Instagram and when I use `var_dump()` on the api response it is populated with a string with the information I want, dispite that when I try to to decode it using `json_decode()` it returns a null and when I check the `json_last_error()` I get `Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded`.

Here is my .php file

```
<?php

function get_popular($user_id,$count){

$api = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/popular?client_id='.$user_id.'&count='.$count;

    $response = file_get_contents($api);
    var_dump($response);

        // Decode the response and build an array
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
        $deco = json_decode($response, TRUE);

        switch (json_last_error()) {
        case JSON_ERROR_NONE:
            echo ' - No errors';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_DEPTH:
            echo ' - Maximum stack depth exceeded';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH:
            echo ' - Underflow or the modes mismatch';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR:
            echo ' - Unexpected control character found';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX:
            echo ' - Syntax error, malformed JSON';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_UTF8:
            echo ' - Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded';
        break;
        default:
            echo ' - Unknown error';
        break;
    }


        var_dump($deco);


}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd try this :

```
$response = iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', utf8_encode($response));
$json = json_decode($response);
```

or without converting :

```
$json = json_decode(utf8_encode($response));
```

EDIT based on the comments :

I noticed that there were some html entities in the json (smileys for instance) :

```
   html_entity_decode($response);
```

Comment: Did that, now I get either Syntax error, malformed JSON or Unexpected control character found

Comment: Try json_decode(html_entity_decode($response), TRUE); It solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue because somewhere I used default `substr()` module and then replaced it with `mb_substr()` and its working fine now